# Is it correct to say ‘Skyping’ in a sentence

Tags: slang, formality, is-it-a-word, conversation

Is it correct to say to my boss ‘ I will be Skyping with you from there’

Comment: Depends on whether your boss knows what "Skyping" is.

Comment: Skyping = meeting by using Skype

Comment: But does your boss know that?

Comment: [Collins CoBuild](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/us/dictionary/english/skype) includes a 'Skype with' example. Already! Impressive.

Comment: *Skype* as a verb has been around for ever -- well, for years, long before it was bought by Microsoft. I've only ever heard/used it with a direct object though. "I will be Skyping you"

Comment: How could the "skype" part of "I will be Skyping with you from there" not be correct?

For the rest, what are you really Asking?

"I will be Skyping with you from there" is correct but what could it really mean?

"…from there…", as opposed to anywhere else, means what?

"…with you…", as opposed to who else, means what?

Comment: @AndrewLeach "Skyping" is also used intransitively. "Sorry, I'm busy skyping."

Comment: @user65526 Well, yes. I meant direct object as opposed to indirect. Using *with* in the way the example has it is uncommon to the point of wrongness, in my experience.

Comment: That might be a dialectal thing, perhaps. BrE doesn't have "meet with" either, although it's becoming more common following AmE influence.